# Autodesk Vault 2023 Lifecycle Change Default Transition For State Change

Tags: windows-10

I am creating a new Lifecycle, Lifecycle B for Vault 2023. This Lifecycle is similar to an existing one, Lifecycle A. A copy of Lifecycle A is taken as the starting point for Lifecycle B.

In Lifecycle A, the main Lifecycle transitions are:

```
Draft in Progress -> For Approval -> Initial Issue
```

In Lifecycle B, a new State is added:

```
Draft in Progress -> For Approval -> Author Finish -> Initial Issue
```

This new Lifecycle State has been added to the Lifecycle's list of States:

[image: Lifecycle States]

Currently the Lifecycle has not been setup correctly: when a drawing is approved, the Approve/Check Job in the Job Queue fails with this error:

```
"Job failed: User does not have permission to move from For Approval to Initial Issue"
```

Vault is trying to automatically change the file State to Initial Issue upon approval, when it should be changing to Author Finish. As such I am investigating the cause of this. In doing so I go to the Lifecycle settings:

```
Tools -> Vault Settings -> Behaviours -> Lifecycles -> Select Lifecycle B and click Edit.
```

I select the For Approval State in the left-hand panel then click Transitions to see the list of Transitions.

I want to change the Transitions so that when a file in the For Approval State is approved, the transition of For Approval -> Author Finish occurs. Further, that the For Approval -> Initial Issue Transition does not occur.

Reviewing the documentation:

https://help.autodesk.com/view/VAULT/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-B4443A39-A621-4E14-8A11-484EFBF3DB90

There is information on how to edit the Criteria for Transitions to occur. There isn't any explanation of how to set a precedence for Transitions or delete unwanted transitions.

How do I change the Lifecycle so that when a file in the For Approval State is approved the State changes to Author Finish?